# Emulate fixed right position

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone-7, internet-explorer-9, mootools

Basically what I am doing is listener, which checks if horizontal scroll has changed or not. If scroll has changed, then it will reposition div, so it always be on top left corner of viewport. It's quite easy with `getScroll()` values.

But how can I change from left to right? Problem is that right: 0 doesn't work as it puts the div to almost in the middle of screen and by scrolling or zooming, it'll stay there (Windows Phone 7 doesn't support `position: fixed`!) Maybe anyone has encountered similar problem and found a fix or a way to calculate right?

Also why is body always 1024px (same as viewport size)? And is there a way to get total sizes of website?

Only variables I have used thus far are:
`window.getScroll().x`, `document.body.scrollWidth` and `window.innerWidth`

```
body {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
}
#rightDiv { 
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}

<body>
<div id='rightDiv'>
    I am in the right-top corner    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: we can only guess if you don't provide any `html` and `css`.

Comment: Code added. I don't know how exactly this should help.

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished by using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    function moveDiv(){
        var divSize = $("#rightDiv").width();
        var windowSize = $("window").width();
        var leftPos = windowSize - divSize;
        var topPos = $("window").scrollTop();
        $("#rightDiv").css({"position":"absolute", "left":leftPos, "top":topPos});
    }
    moveDiv();
    $("window").scroll(function(){
        moveDiv();
    }
    );
    $("window").resize(function(){
        moveDiv();
    }
    );
});
```

This will set up your div to position itself to the right of the screen when the document loads, and then anytime the screen is scrolled, it will recalculate the position.

Essentially, we do calculations based on the width of your div and the size of your window to determine what left position will place the div in the top right corner.  Even though it's positioned from the left, it will still give the effect of being in the top right of the screen.  Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on IE mobile. windowSize is always 1024px, no matter how large the page width actually is (page is unresponsible webdesign.)

Comment: Just for clarification, when you refer to IE mobile, you're talking about the inbuilt windows phone browser, correct?

Comment: I'm talking about Internet Explorer 9 which is on Windows Phone 7 :)